# How to fix display error with GNOME Shell on Fedora 19?

Tags: fedora, gnome3, nvidia, display

I got the following problem:

Well, just installed Fedora 19 alongside to my Debian installation. While GNOME Shell is working perfectly fine when running with Debian, there are some strange display errors (e.g. coloured backgrounds of icons; when opening the dash (where all installed applications are listed) the background not only darkens but turns completely black).

[image: Image describing the issue here.]

Some information about the actual machine running now Fedora 19:
CPU: AMD Athlon 5050e, GPU: nVidia 7800GT (128 MB GFX RAM), RAM: 2 GB
(I assume this is all information that's necessary, if not, please ask in the comments).

Has anyone any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: AHHH! My eyes! What driver are you using, free nouveahu (or however is wrote) or proprietary. If you use one then switch for the other. If gets worse, switch back. Got worse yet again? Remove `xorg.conf`.

Comment: we'll, I was using nouveau (all in favour of free software) but it seems the version shipping with fedora is not really working properly on my card.. (even though the one that comes with Debian Wheezy does work fine.. but Debian does not accept the power saving features of my chipset)

Comment: What version of drivers you have running on Debian and Fedora? According with [this](http://www.fedoraforum.org/forum/showthread.php?p=1576361) seems like a *expected* problem with Fedora, but no with other distributions.

Comment: Whatever you mean with "expected" problem, but yes, running Debian (or Suse) there's no problem at all, with Fedora there is. Could you please tell me, how to find out the currently used version of the driver? (Problem with Fedora already is persistent with Live-DVD drivers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this card, i should think is nouveau driver. Try the propertary driver in the nvidia page.

Comment: We'll using the proprietary driver the card actually works fine.. even though I really would appreciate to use the nouveau driver, but there's no way of downgrading this to the version shipping with Debian (as this does work)?

Comment: Probably with this http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2013/fedora-19-nvidia-guide/

Comment: Just to complete this topic sometime: After finally upgrading to proprietary drivers the issue has been fixed.

Comment: Please mark the question as solved and vote for the answer that help to solve the issue.

Comment: Did so. Anyway, to add some more remark: I used the drivers packaged as RPM from RPM-fusion repositories. (which work just as fine. You only have to use the old 304-stage not the current ones.)